# Spring security with both SSO and form login

Tags: spring-boot, spring-security, spring-security-oauth2, keycloak

My application had form login and now I want to integrate my freeIPA account using Keycloak.

I have 2 `WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter` below

SecurityConfiguration.java

```java
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
@Order(1)
public class SecurityConfiguration extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {
    private final AccountDetailsService accountDetailsService;

    private static final String[] IGNORED_RESOURCE_LIST = new String[]{
            "/resources/**",
            "/static/**",
            "/webjars/**",
            "/plugins/**",
            "/imgs/**",
            "/fonts/**",
            "/vendors/**",
            "/flags/**",
            "/js/**",
            "/sso/login",
            "/css/**"};

    private static final String[] PERMIT_ALL_RESOURCE_LIST = new String[]{
            "/actuator/health/**",
            "/login/**",
            "/json/**",
            "/auth/**",
            "/error/**"};

    @Autowired
    public SecurityConfiguration(AccountDetailsService accountDetailsService) {
        this.accountDetailsService = accountDetailsService;
    }

    @Override
    public void configure(WebSecurity web) {
        web.ignoring().antMatchers(IGNORED_RESOURCE_LIST);
    }

    @Override
    protected void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) {
        auth.authenticationProvider(authenticationProvider());
    }

    @Bean
    public DaoAuthenticationProvider authenticationProvider() {
        DaoAuthenticationProvider authProvider
                = new DaoAuthenticationProvider();
        authProvider.setUserDetailsService(accountDetailsService);
        authProvider.setPasswordEncoder(encoder());
        return authProvider;
    }

    @Bean
    public PasswordEncoder encoder() {
        return new BCryptPasswordEncoder();
    }

    @Bean
    public SessionRegistry sessionRegistry() {
        return new SessionRegistryImpl();
    }

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http.csrf().disable();

        http.authorizeRequests()
                .antMatchers(PERMIT_ALL_RESOURCE_LIST).permitAll()
                .anyRequest().authenticated()
                .and().formLogin().loginPage("/auth/login").failureUrl("/auth/login?message=error").permitAll()
                .and().logout().permitAll();

        http.sessionManagement().maximumSessions(1).sessionRegistry(sessionRegistry()).expiredUrl("/auth/login");
    }
}
```

and KeycloakSecurityConfig.java

```java
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
@ComponentScan(basePackageClasses = KeycloakSecurityComponents.class)
@Order(2)
public class KeycloakSecurityConfig extends KeycloakWebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    @Autowired
    public void configureGlobal(
            AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {

        KeycloakAuthenticationProvider keycloakAuthenticationProvider
                = keycloakAuthenticationProvider();
        keycloakAuthenticationProvider.setGrantedAuthoritiesMapper(
                new SimpleAuthorityMapper());
        auth.authenticationProvider(keycloakAuthenticationProvider);
    }

    @Bean
    public KeycloakSpringBootConfigResolver KeycloakConfigResolver() {
        return new KeycloakSpringBootConfigResolver();
    }

    @Bean
    @Override
    protected SessionAuthenticationStrategy sessionAuthenticationStrategy() {
        return new RegisterSessionAuthenticationStrategy(
                new SessionRegistryImpl());
    }

    @Bean
    public SessionRegistry sessionRegistry() {
        return new SessionRegistryImpl();
    }

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        super.configure(http);
        http.authorizeRequests().anyRequest().authenticated();
    }
}
```

And from login page I had a button Login with Keycloak. It redirects to Keycloak login page using url `/sso/login` but after logged in I was redirected back to application login page.

Can anybody enlight me this case. How can I implement both form login and SSO login in my application?

Thanks in advance. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: The keycloak adapter protects every request you make except the ones for `/sso/login` and `/sso/logout` endpoints. These special calls are supposed to be handled by itself, not for you to be used as an entry point (you can browse elsewhere except `/` and those two endpoints and the adapter should work properly). First I would try to make the keycloak authentication work by its own, then try to integrate it with your own login form.

Comment: Keycloak work normally if I remove SecurityConfiguration class

Comment: When you try to access a protected resource, the KC adapter redirects you to the KC login page. The SS form login does the same. How do you intend to make a difference between them? Keep in mind you can make KC read your application users, maybe it deserves configuring KC to do it and go only with KC instead of trying to configure both security mechanisms.

Comment: My idea is after logged in successful with KC, I will link KC account id with my app users via email and set the authentication programmatic. But when I call a url, the principal is still annonymousUser. Can you suggest me some flows? Any article should I read?

Comment: Then you don't have the KC adapter properly working. When the KC adapter is configured, the KC user must be in the session principal. Also, for achieving what you describe, you don't need to configure both login mechanisms. Just properly have KC working and then link the KC user id or user e-mail to the extra attributes in your DB.